# Расширение класса перегруженными операторами C#

Tags: c#, ооп, biginteger

Имеется класс `BigInteger` библиотеки BouncyCastle, который имеет функции вида `BigInteger.Add(BigInteger)`, `Sub`, `Multiply` и т.д. Так вот, для удобной работы хочется создать перегруженные методы `operator+`, `operator-` и т.д, т.е. расширить данный класс. Как это можно сделать правильно и по канонам ООП?

Для пользователя все должно выглядеть примерно так:

```
BigInteger A=5,B=10;
BigInteger C = A+B;
```

Comment: если класс не запечатанный (sealed), то наследование

Comment: Но в таком случае мы создадим Новый класс, в котором реализуем перегрузку операторов. А можно ли все реализовать так, чтобы для пользователя все было прозрачно(т.е. без явных приведений типов и прочего) и при этом остаться в пределах исходного (BigIntrger) класса?

Comment: А чем не угодил `System.Numerics.Biginteger`?

Comment: В учебных целях реализуем шифрование\подписывание RSA, соответственно необходимы методы для генерации псевдопростых чисел\проверки на простоту.

Comment: @ShinaZin, одно из принципов ООП - инкапсуляция, которая, вроде бы, противоречит тому, чтоб в него влезали и что-то меняли. Единственное, что еще возможно - методы расширения, но они не имеют возможности расширять перегрузку методов
Еще как вариант, который может помочь - создать в другом нейспейсе класс с точно таким же именем и наследовать от класса с таким же именем, но с исходного нейспейса, а потом просто чуть подкорректировать using там, где используется исходный BigInteger, таким образом Вы подмените оригинальный класс на свой унаследованный, и все будут рады

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Боюсь у вас ничего не получится. Дело в том, что интересующий вас синтаксис - 
обеспечивается перегрузкой операторов, и без возможности модифицировать исходники класса `BigInteger` вы эту задачу выполнить не сможете. Теоретически  вам могла бы помочь такая возможность, как методы расширения (extension methods), но этот синтаксический сахар применим только по отношению к экземплярам, а перегрузка операторов реализуется статическими методами.
Наследование тут вам тоже вряд ли поможет, во всяком случае для получения результата в том виде, в котором вы хотите. Вы, конечно, можете создать класс-наследник `BigInteger`, перегрузить в нём арифметические операторы с помощью соответствующих статических методов, но эти операторы будут работать только применимо к вашему классу-наследнику, то есть писать что-то вроде

```
BigInteger A=5,B=10;
BigInteger C = A+B;
```

вы не сможете

Comment: может распишешь подробнее почему?

Comment: _писать что-то вроде ... вы не сможете_ - сможете с помощью маленького трюка. Написал в комментарии к вопросу

Comment: Что ж, спасибо всем за участие и подробные разъяснения!) Жаль, конечно, что нет такой возможности, но вариант с наследованием и разными неймспейсами(см ответ @Qutrix)  в моем случае вроде как приемлемый. Ибо не так много зависимостей от данного класса.